# How would I access a pop ui button?

Tags: ruby, xpath, watir, firewatir, watir-webdriver

I have a pop up button that is triggered by deleting an object. How can I click the button if I can seem to find it.

I have used xpath like so:

```
$browser.button(:xpath, "/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/button").click
```

Here is a code snippet:
[image: The text is Highlighted.]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
browser.span(:text => "Delete").click
```

or

```
browser.span(:class => "ui-button-text).click
```

or

```
browser.button(:class => /ui-button/).click
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure exactly which button are you trying to click. :)
But if you are trying to click on the Delete button shown in the DOM snippet above then, you can try this xpath. `"//button/span[.='Delete']"`

Hope this helps.